# Appcenter Push: Unable to display notification

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to implement a event handler to see if a custom data attribute is present and if so remove some app data. The issue is now that no due to the event delegate i cannot show the notifications that do not match the custom data value.

I need to display the push notification if it doesn't have the custom data key. How can i do this in Xamarin forms?

```
private void SetupPushNotificationHandle()
    {
        // This should come before AppCenter.Start() is called
        // Avoid duplicate event registration:
        if (!AppCenter.Configured)
        {
            Push.PushNotificationReceived += (sender, e) =&gt;
            {
                OceanBusiness business = CoreDependencyService.GetBusinessLayer&lt;OceanBusiness&gt;();
                // If there is custom data associated with the notification,
                // print the entries
                if (e.CustomData != null)
                {
                    foreach (var key in e.CustomData.Keys)
                    {
                        switch (key)
                        {
                            case CoreSettings.ClearData:
                            {
                                if(key.ToLower() == "true")
                                    business.RemoveData();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            };
        }
```

I have seen how to do this in Xamarin.Android but not in Xamarin.iOS. As such answers that do not show how to do both will not address this question.

Comment: You can reflect your problem in AppCenter Console https://appcenter.ms/apps

Comment: Already did so and was told that they couldn't hel.